# how to displayed key and value in functional component inside return part

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to displayed all the object value one by one in screen . I am getting map function is undefined
sample data array . For setting the array i am using hooks

```
{ 
    first: 5
    second: 6
    StrtDt: "2019-03-06"
    seconds: 80
    days: 7
    mins: 1
}


const [attributesCodes, setattributesCodes] = React.useState({});

setattributesCodes(sampledataArray);
```

expected screen

```
<div>
    <label>first : </label><label>5</label>
    <label>second : </label><label>5</label>
    <label>StrtDt : </label><label>2019-03-06</label>
    <label>seconds : </label><label>8</label>
</div>
```

i tried the below code but it showing issue in map

```
return (
<div>
{attributesCodes.map((data, index) => (
           <label>index : </label><label>data</label>

          ))}
          
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
<div>
{Object.keys(attributesCodes).map((key) => (
           <label>{key} : </label><label>attributesCodes[key]</label>

          ))}
          
    </div>
)
```

Please Try using this approach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

It throws error because `attributesCodes` is an object. Use e.g. `Object.entries` instead, then map over it.

```
{Object.entries(attributesCodes).map(([key, value], index) => (
    <label key={index}>{key}: {value}</label>
))}
```

Comment: Also it seems that there are ````,```` missing in the object definition of the OP, ````{ first: 5, second: 6, StrtDt: "2019-03-06", seconds: 80, days: 7,mins: 1}````

Comment: @michaelT Yeah, I guess this is just a minimal reproducible code sample...

Answer (score 1):

You can't map across an object so you will need to either define attributesCodes as an array or access the object using Object.keys, Object.values, or Object.entries.

```
return (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(attributesCodes).map(key => (
           <label>{key} : </label><label>attributesCodes[key]</label>
         ))}  
    </div>
)
```